# How to do a custom insert inside a python-eve app

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, eve

I have some custom flask methods in an eve app that need to communicate with a telnet device and return a result, but I also want to pre-populate data into some resources after retrieving data from this telnet device, like so:

```
@app.route("/get_vlan_description", methods=['POST'])
def get_vlan_description():
    switch = prepare_switch(request)
    result = dispatch_switch_command(switch, 'get_vlan_description')

    # TODO: populate vlans resource with result data and return status
```

My settings.py looks like this:

```
SERVER_NAME = '127.0.0.1:5000'
DOMAIN = {
    'vlans': {
        'id': {
            'type': 'integer',
            'required': True,
            'unique': True
        },
        'subnet': {
            'type': 'string',
            'required': True
        },
        'description': {
            'type': 'boolean',
            'default': False
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble finding docs or source code for how to access a mongo resource directly and insert this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into the [`on_insert`](http://python-eve.org/features.html#the-on-insert-event-hooks) hook? From the documentation:

> When documents are about to be stored in the database, both `on_insert(resource, documents)` and `on_insert_<resource>(documents)` events are raised. **Callback functions could hook into these events to arbitrarily add new fields, or edit existing ones**. `on_insert` is raised on every resource being updated while `on_insert_<resource>` is raised when the `<resource>` endpoint has been hit with a POST request. In both circumstances, the event will be raised only if at least one document passed validation and is going to be inserted. `documents` is a list and only contains documents ready for insertion *(payload documents that did not pass validation are not included)*.

So, if I get what you want to achieve, you could have something like this:

```
def telnet_service(resource, documents):
    """ 
        fetch data from telnet device;
        update 'documents' accordingly 
    """
    pass

app = Eve()
app.on_insert += telnet_service

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Note that this way you don't have to mess with the database directly as Eve will take care of that.

If you don't want to store the telnet data but only *send it back* along with the fetched documents, you can hook to [`on_fetch`](http://python-eve.org/features.html#the-on-fech-event-hooks) instead.

Lastly, if you really want to use the data layer you can use `app.data.driver`as seen in [this example snippet](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#basic-authentication).

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to change which resource is being written to or to write to multiple resources during the same hook?

Comment: Nope. Unless, I guess, you resort to using the data driver directly.

Comment: Is it remotely acceptable to use the test_client to achieve what @CarlYoungblood is asking, to operate on other resources?

Comment: You could probably just hit the other resource endpoints from your callback function, using requests or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

use **post_internal**

Usage [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319716/using-eves-db-layer-without-http/25493169#25493169):

```
from run import app
from eve.methods.post import post_internal

payload = {
    "firstname": "Ray",
    "lastname": "LaMontagne",
    "role": ["contributor"]
}

with app.test_request_context():
    x = post_internal('people', payload)
    print(x)
```